# How to prevent loss hover in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm developing some page when I use `Raphael` liblary to draw some items.

[my App](http://jsbin.com/irujit/1/edit)

So my **problem** is in that when I'm moving to some `rect` it growing up but when my mouse is on text which is positioning on my `rect`, it loss his hover. You can see it on my app example.

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('holder'), 500, object.length * 100);
drawLine(paper, aType.length, bType.length, cType.length, cellSize, padding);

process = function(i,label)
{ 
    txt = paper.text(390,((i+1)* cellSize) - 10,label.devRepo)
        .attr({ stroke: "none", opacity: 0, "font-size": 20});
    var a = paper.rect(200, ((i+1)* cellSize) - 25, rectWidth, rectHeight)
        .hover(function()
        {  
            this.animate({ transform : "s2"}, 1000, "elastic");
            this.prev.animate({opacity: 1}, 500, "elastic");
            this.next.attr({"font-size" : 30});
        }, 
        function()
        {       
            this.animate({ transform : "s1" }, 1000, "elastic");
            this.prev.animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
            this.next.attr({"font-size" : 15});
        });
}
```

I have tried `e.preventDefault();` on hover of `this.next` and some other solutions but it's doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you format your code?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I hope now it's better.

Answer (score 3):

Most people will suggest you place a transparent rectangle over the box and the labels and attach the hover functions to that instead. (If memory serves, you have to make the opacity 0.01 instead of 0 to prevent the object from losing its attached events.) This works fine, but I don't love this solution; it feels hacky and clutters the page with unnecessary objects.

Instead, I recommend this: Remove the second function from the hover, making it functionally a mouseover function only. Before you draw any of the rectangles and labels, make a rectangular "mat" the size of the paper. Then, attach the function that minimizes the label as a mouseover on the mat. In other words, you're changing the trigger from mousing *out* of the box to mousing *over* the area outside of it.

I left a tiny bit of opacity and color on the mat to be sure it's working. You can just change the color to your background color.

```
  var mat = paper.rect(0, 0, paper.width, paper.height).attr({fill: "#F00", opacity: 0.1});
```

Now, you want to make a container for all the rectangles so you can loop through them to see which need to be minimized. I made an object called "rectangles" that contains the objects we're concerned with. Then:

```
  mat.mouseover(function () {
    for (var c = 0; c < rectangles.length; c += 1) {
      //some measure to tell if rectangle is presently expanded
      if (rectangles[c].next.attr("font-size")) {
        rectangles[c].animate({                  
              transform : "s1"
            }, 1000, "elastic");
        rectangles[c].prev.animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
        rectangles[c].next.attr({"font-size" : 15});                  
      }
    }
  });
```

Then I just removed the mouseout function from the individual rectangles.

[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/irujit/3/edit)

To be clear, this will have some downsides: If people run the mouse around really fast, they can expand several rectangles at the same time. This is remedied as soon as the mouse touches the mat. I think the functionality looks pretty nice. But the invisible mats is always an option.

Comment: I dig that solution.  Much cleaner than my own =)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small extension to Raphael - called `hoverInBounds` - that resolves this limitation.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/amustill/Bh276/1

```
Raphael.el.hoverInBounds = function(inFunc, outFunc) {
    var inBounds = false;

    // Mouseover function. Only execute if `inBounds` is false.
    this.mouseover(function() {
        if (!inBounds) {
            inBounds = true;
            inFunc.call(this);
        }
    });

    // Mouseout function
    this.mouseout(function(e) {
        var x = e.offsetX || e.clientX,
            y = e.offsetY || e.clientY;

        // Return `false` if we're still inside the element's bounds
        if (this.isPointInside(x, y)) return false;

        inBounds = false;
        outFunc.call(this);
    });

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Looks, nice but can you show me how to use it in my jsBin? I have placed your `hoverInBounds` as `hover` but it looks a little strange http://jsbin.com/irujit/9/edit

Comment: @MateuszRogulski Unfortunately I haven't got the time to debug your app. Looking quickly, I would recommend that you place your text labels as an attribute on the rectangles themselves, as I have done in my demo. This prevents the requirement to use `this.next()`, as you can simple use `this.text` for example.